# Issues sending key events to browser window autohotkey

Tags: autohotkey

I am trying to open up a webpage and save it as a complete file. This should be a relatively easy task for autohotkey. For some reason my script is not sending key events to the window. Here's the script:

```
#NoEnv  ; Recommended for performance and compatibility with future AutoHotkey releases.
; #Warn All, StdOut  ; Enable warnings to assist with detecting common errors.
SendMode Input  ; Recommended for new scripts due to its superior speed and reliability.
SetWorkingDir %A_ScriptDir%  ; Ensures a consistent starting directory.

Run, www.google.com
WinWaitActive firefox.exe
sleep, 4000
ControlSend, ahk_class MozillaWindowClass, ^s
```

What would be a better approach to this problem?

Comment: Since you are waiting for the window to become active, is there a reason why you are using ControlSend rather than regular Send?

Comment: Nope it still doesn't work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is my solution:

```
Run, www.google.com
WinWaitActive ahk_exe firefox.exe
sleep, 4000
Send ^s
```

There were two main things that were changed for this to work

1. Include `ahk_exe` before the name of the exe in the `WinWaitActive` conditional
2. Removed the `ControlSend` and replaced it with a regular `Send`, since we are already waiting for the Window to be activated

Hope this helps, feel free to ask for any more clarification or help if you need it

Answer (score 0):

```
ControlSend, ahk_parent, ^s, ahk_class MozillaWindowClass
```